# Is asynchronous messaging in Tyrus Websocket implementation orderly?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-ee-7, tyrus

If I use one thread to repeatedly call the [Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net/) implementation of [RemoteEndpoint.Async.sendText(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/RemoteEndpoint.Async.html#sendText%28java.lang.String%29), will my messages always go away on the wire orderly as I, the client, sent them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they should (if you see something else, feel free to file a bug - https://java.net/jira/browse/TYRUS).

Comment: Pavel, what would my life be without you :)